# Drop rows based on a value in a row beneath it | Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to write a code that drops rows based on a value in a row beneath it.

Currently, I use this code, which is very slow with large data sets (tens of thousands of rows) since it's iterating through all rows:

```
def f(df):
    current_row = 0
    max_row = len(df.index) - 1
    row_indexes_to_be_dropped = []
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if current_row == max_row:  # If the current row is the last, check cond1 and cond2 on current row and decide if it will be dropped
            if (row['cond1'] == 'False') or (row['cond2'] == 'False'):
                row_indexes_to_be_dropped.append(index)
        elif df.iloc[current_row + 1]['cond2'] == 'False':  # If the current row is not the last, check cond2 on next row and decide if the current row will be dropped
            row_indexes_to_be_dropped.append(index)
        current_row += 1

    df = df.drop(row_indexes_to_be_dropped)
    return df

df_grouped = df_more_records.groupby('ID').apply(f)
```

Is there a way to write this with functions that work with whole vectors?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Never use loops if you can get around it. You did not provide a fully working example, but I'd do it like this:

```py
mask = (df['cond1'] == 'False') or (df['cond2'] == 'False')
df.drop(df.index[mask.shift(1, fill_value=False).values.flatten()])
```

Answer (score 0):

1. use itertuples instead of iterrows, it will speed up the literation

   for row in  df.itertuples():
   value = row.column_name
2. you can use filter instead of row literation

   df_filter= df.loc[df['column_name'] = condition]

Answer (score 0):

- no sample data so generated simple data to demonstrate
- use `shift(-1)` to test condition of next row
- `drop()` rows where condition is matched

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"value":np.random.randint(1,3,10)})

# drop rows where value in next row is 1
df.drop(df.loc[df["value"].shift(-1).eq(1)].index)
```